# Why is my code not reading EOF correctly, though reading others correctly

Tags: c, file, eof

Program not detecting EOF.
Program counts the number of times "Glassdoor" comes in a file.
It detects other characters and words and end of line and reaches the end of file correctly, but then does not go into the condition to detect EOF, rather reads and starts the last line again and again in infinite loop and never exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <conio.h> - Does not exist in gcc
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 64

int main ()
{

    // Declare file *
    FILE* fp;

    // Get file path and open file
    //fp = fopen ("file_name.txt","r");
    fopen_s(&fp, "file_name.txt", "r");

    // Declare variables for line and word
    char *line, *word; 
    line = (char*) malloc (MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    word = (char*) malloc (MAX_WORD_SIZE);

    // Declare and initiaize count
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    int j;

    //Read a line till EOF is met
    while (1)
    {
        fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp );

        i = 0, j = 0;
        //for ( i=0, j=0; i<MAX_LINE_LENGTH; i++, j++)
        while (*(line+i) != '\n')
        {

            // Extract word
            if ( *(line+i) == EOF)
            {
                printf ("The file has \"Glassdoor\" %u times", count);
                getchar();
                return 0; // exit();
            }
            else if ( (*(line+i) == ' '))
            {
                // NUll terminate the word to make it a string
                *(word+j) = '\0';
                // Compare
                if (strcmp (word, "Glassdoor") == 0)
                    count ++;
                // Make j = -1, after increment it will be 0 for new word
                j = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                *(word+j) = *(line+i);
            }
            // Increment both i and j to go to next character
            i++; j++;
        }

            // If end of line - do the same thing on last word as is for every word
            // NUll terminate the word to make it a string
            *(word + j) = '\0';
            // Compare
            if (strcmp(word, "Glassdoor") == 0)
                count++;
            // Make j = -1, after increment it will be 0 for new word
            //j = -1;

            if (strcmp(word, "lastword") == 0)
            {
                //only for debugging
                printf("Reached last word \n");
            }
    }

    return -1; // Error - it should not reach here and exit this way
}
```

Comment: What documentation convinced you that `fgets` will populate the specified output buffer with the value of `EOF` ? That isn't how the function works

Comment: `fgets()` doesn't put an `EOF` value into the buffer when it encounters the end of file - it signals that condition by returning `NULL`.

Comment: The loop construction would be better as `while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: `EOF` is not a character; it's an (encoded) indication of error [with a value distinct from any valid character].

Comment: Your program isn't detecting EOF because it isn't checking the value returned by `fgets`.